# retrieve id of a div by using attr("id"); is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

index.php

```
 if (idx == 8) {
     var str="<?php echo $username1; ?>";
     document.write(str);
     jQuery.get("usermessage.php?username="+str, function(data) {
       document.write(data);
       var msgIDss = $(".messagepiece:last").attr("id");
       document.write(msgIDss);
     });
 }
```

usermessage.php

```
$username1=$_GET["username"];
$query2 = "SELECT id, message, datetime FROM messages WHERE username='{$username1}' ORDER BY id";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2,$connection) or die (mysql_error());
confirm_query($result2);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result2);

while($userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
  $msgID= $userinfo['id'];
  echo "<div class=\"messagepiece\" id=" . $msgID . ">" . $userinfo['id'] . 
    $userinfo['message'] . "<br><span style=\"font-size:13px; color:orange;\">" . 
    $userinfo['datetime'] . "</span></div>|";       
}
```

My problem is `document.write(msgIDss)` display empty / blank value.

on index.php, I have tested document.write(data); and it works. I have tested `document.write(str)` and it work too, so `if (idx == 8)` is not the problem. I also tested open usermessage.php manually and it success display all the div(s), so usermessage.php page is not the problem. I guess the problem is on this line of code `var msgIDss = $(".messagepiece:last").attr("id")`. How to fix it?

Comment: you shouldn't post PHP code here, but rather resulting HTML code.

Comment: Agree with @Col. Shrapnel above, the best way for us to help if the below solutions didn't work is to post the HTML output of your script and post the exact javascript/jquery you are using. Someone should be able to give you an answer more easily then.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that because you're not wrapping the 'id' attribute's value in double-quotes, the browser you are testing in does not pickup the id properly.

Try the following:

`echo "<div class=\"messagepiece\" id=\"" . $msgID . "\">"`

Comment: That's my guess too. It would be prettier to use single-quoted strings and bypass the escaping altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
echo "<div class=\"messagepiece\" id=\"" . $msgID . "\">"
```

Note the added escaped quotes around the `id` value.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried both echo "<div class=\"messagepiece\" id=\"" . $msgID . "\">" and echo "<div class=\"messagepiece\" id=\"ddd-" . $msgID . "\">", but they both are not working too. Any other solution? Please help me.

Comment: @zac1987, could you post a sample of the HTML that your PHP is outputting?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the id attribute is starting with a number. Using a string as prefix should fix:

```
echo "<div class=\"messagepiece\" id=\"message-" . $msgID . "\">" ......
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried both echo "<div class=\"messagepiece\" id=\"" . $msgID . "\">" and echo "<div class=\"messagepiece\" id=\"ddd-" . $msgID . "\">", but they both are not working too. Any other solution?